# Can't seem to get jQuery UI Date Picker to work correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to embed jQuery UI Date Picker.
I have got the code from here - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is I can't see the actual datepicker but only the input box even when clicking over. Are there any additional steps I should go through in order to make it work or is there something else wrong I'm doing?

Comment: Are you getting some errors in the console?

Comment: That code seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the console you will see something like this

> file:///Users/David/Developer/code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   file:///Users/David/Developer/code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js Failed
>   to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   file:///Users/David/Developer/code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Just add `http://` when you add the resources and will work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: And please, check the answer as the correct answer :)